# Are there collaborative drawing software?

Tags: software-recommendation, design-process, collaboration

I was reflecting on Google Docs today and wondering if there are any graphic design software that include some real-time collaborative features? I'm talking about creating per se, not project management.

I could see this being potentially useful for remote working or teamwork. I've never seen anything like this in the Adobe suite but I'm not knowledgeable of open source/online/or mobile graphic design oriented software. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: @Billy Kerr when I say real time, I mean drawing together simultaneously, not just file sharing features

Comment: Sorry I turned that into an answer, but you are right Adobe's Creative Cloud is essentially a file sharing service.

Comment: There are few conference suites that make a shared whiteboard, does that count.

Comment: @joojaa IMO yes, as long as it's possible to sketch in them

Answer (score 3):

You might want to chek out [Figma](https://www.figma.com/) which emphasizes its real-time collaboration features.

It is geared towards interface design, bit since it's a vector editor, it could potentially be used for anything else.

There is also [vectr](https://vectr.com/), which seems to have collaboration features (but I have not tested that)

Comment: Looks like vectr's collaboration feature is effectively a view-only link which allows clients or collaborators to watch the designer work in close-to-realtime. A bit voyueristic.   
<br/>figma however, looks like exactly what OP was asking for - online, real-time collaboration, connexions between graphcis and coding for interface design - pretty slick really. However, worth noting it's optimised FOR UI design - not say logo dev or generalised illustration.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe's Creative Cloud allows collaboration with others. You can read more about it [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/collaboration.html)

> You can collaborate with other users and share a private Creative
>   Cloud Library or folder from your Creative Cloud account with
>   specified users. All invited users can then work co-operatively with
>   read-only (locked) assets in a shared private folder or library.
>   Collaborators can view, edit, rename, move, or delete contents of the
>   shared folder or library if they've been granted the necessary access
>   rights and permissions.

Another thing that might be useful is Adobe's InCopy - which allows collaborative working in InDesign while a document is open.  More info [here](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/incopy.html?mv=product&mv2=accc)

Comment: See my comment on question above

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you define "graphic design", but try [Drawpile](https://drawpile.net/)